# Undefined Reference to a function which is defined already

Tags: c, compiler-errors, makefile

I am trying to construct an expression compiler.
When I try to compile my following main.c, it gives me the following errors:

```
    cc -O -o compile error.o lex.o table.o main.o code.o
    main.o: In function `terms':
    main.c:(.text+0x1be): undefined reference to `popopand'
    main.c:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `popopand'
    main.c:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to `popoptor'
    main.o: In function `term':
    main.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `factoor'
    main.o: In function `expresses':
    main.c:(.text+0x302): undefined reference to `popopand'
    main.c:(.text+0x309): undefined reference to `popopand'
    main.c:(.text+0x32b): undefined reference to `popoptor'
    main.o: In function `stmt':
    main.c:(.text+0x4cf): undefined reference to `popopand'
    main.c:(.text+0x4d6): undefined reference to `popopand'
    main.c:(.text+0x4dd): undefined reference to `popoptor'
    main.o: In function `stmts':
    main.c:(.text+0x582): undefined reference to `eerror'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

And my main.c is following code:

```
#include "global.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define STACK 100

int opandstk[STACK],optorstk[STACK];
int topoptor=-1,topopand=-1;
int curtoken;

main(argc,argv) int argc;char *argv[];{

    char msg[BUFSIZ];
    char *sp;

    if(argc!=2){
        sprintf(msg,"usage: %s filename",argv[0]);
        error(msg,PANIC);
    }
    emit(TEXT,BLANK,BLANK);
    curtoken=yygettoken();
    if(stmts()){
        if(curtoken=='\n' || curtoken==EOFILE){
            curtoken=yygettoken();
            if(curtoken==EOFILE){
                emit(EXIT,insert("0"),BLANK);
                data();
            }
        }
    }
    else
        error("end of file or end of line expected.",PANIC);
    exit(0);
}
stmts(){
    if(curtoken=='\n' || curtoken==EOFILE)
        return 1;
    if(curtoken==IDENT){
        if(stmt())
            if(stmts())
                return 1;
    }
    error("end of file or end of line or identifier expected.",PANIC);
}
stmt(){
    int rhs;
    if(curtoken==IDENT){
        pushopand(lookup(yytext));
        curtoken=yygettoken();
        if(curtoken=='='){
            pushoptor(ASSIGN);
            curtoken=yygettoken();
            if(express()){
                if(curtoken==';'){
                    curtoken=yygettoken();
                    rhs=popopand();
                    emit(popoptor(),popopand(),rhs);
                    return 1;
                }
                error("';' expected.",PANIC);
            }

        }
        error("'=' expected.",PANIC);
    }
    error("identifier expected.",PANIC);
}
express(){
    if(curtoken==IDENT || curtoken==INTEGER || curtoken=='('){
        if(term() && expresses())
            return 1;
    }
    error("identifier,integer or '(' expected.",PANIC);
}
expresses(){
    int lhs,rhs,temp;
    if(curtoken==')' || curtoken==';')
        return 1;
    if(curtoken=='-' || curtoken=='+'){
        if(curtoken=='-')
            pushoptor(SUB);
        else
            pushoptor(ADD);
        curtoken=yygettoken();
        if (term()){
            rhs=popopand();
            lhs=popopand();
            temp=mktmp();
            emit(ASSIGN,temp,lhs);
            emit(popoptor(),temp,rhs);
            pushopand(temp);
            if(expresses())
                return 1;
        }
    }
    error("')',';','-' or '+'expected.",PANIC);
}
term(){
    if(curtoken==IDENT || curtoken==INTEGER || curtoken=='(')
        if(factor() && terms())
            return 1;
    error("identifier,integer or '(' expected.",PANIC);
}
terms(){
    int lhs,rhs,temp;
    if(curtoken=='/' || curtoken=='*'){
        if(curtoken=='/')
            pushoptor(DIV);
        else
            pushoptor(MULT);
        curtoken=yygettoken();
        if (factor()){
            rhs=popopand();
            lhs=popopand();
            temp=mktmp();
            emit(ASSIGN,temp,lhs);
            emit(popoptor(),temp,rhs);
            pushopand(temp);
            if(terms())
                return 1;
        }

    }
    else if(curtoken=='-' || curtoken=='+'|| curtoken==')' || curtoken==';')
        return 1;
    error("'/','*','-','+',';'or ')'expected.",PANIC);
}
factor(){
    if(curtoken=='('){
        curtoken=yygettoken();
        if (express()){
            if(curtoken==')'){
                curtoken=yygettoken();
                return 1;
            }
            error("')' expected",PANIC);
        }

    }
    if(curtoken==INTEGER || curtoken==IDENT){
        pushopand(lookup(yytext));
        curtoken=yygettoken();
        return 1;
    }
    error("'(',integer or identifier expected",PANIC);
}
pushopand(i) int i;{
    if(++topopand==STACK)
        error("internal error: operand stack overflow",PANIC);
    opandstk[topopand]=i;
}
int 
popopand(){
    if(topopand==-1)
        error("internal error: operand stack underflow",PANIC);
    return (opandstk[topopand--]);
}
pushoptor(i) int i;{
    if(++topoptor==STACK)
        error("internal error: operator stack overflow",PANIC);
    opandstk[topoptor]=i;
}
int 
popoptor(){
    if(topoptor==-1)
        error("internal error: operator stack underflow",PANIC);
    return (opandstk[topoptor--]);
}
int 
mktmp(){
    static int seed=0;
    char name[BUFSIZ];
    sprintf(name,"-xxx%d",seed++);
    return (insert(name,NONLITERAL));
}
```

And my Makefile is:

```
compile: error.o lex.o table.o code.o main.o
    cc -O -o compile error.o lex.o table.o main.o code.o
main.o: global.h
    cc -c -O main.c
code.o: global.h
    cc -c -O code.c
error.o:global.h
    cc -c -O error.c    
lex.o:  global.h
    cc -c -O lex.c
table.o: global.h
    cc -c -O table.c
```

Will any mentor advice me to resolve those errors?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your syntax for `main` is correct?

Comment: @haccks ??? `main()` is right in the code OP posted...

Comment: @haccks: it's "correct" for 1980's code....

Comment: @H2CO3; Strange to me!

Comment: @Mat; So, is that obsolete now?

Comment: @haccks It's technically correct, but it's strongly discouraged.

Comment: @haccks: yes. Like the imlicit int return type that OP is using inconsistently. user2015915, do yourself a favor and use proper prototypes for your functions, turn on your compiler's warnings to maximum levels and fix anything it's not happy with.

Comment: @H2CO3; What about function prototypes? Is there any old feature of C that allow the function reference without prototypes (if the definitions are not before main)?

Comment: Mixing ANSI and K&R style function definitions may be causing trouble.

Comment: @haccks You can call an undeclared function in C89 (not in C99), and its signature will be inferred from the first call. Very bad idea.

Comment: `main()` is legal (but obsolescent) in C90, and a constraint violation in C99 and later. `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is correct and recommended in all versions of C since C90.

Comment: Actually I am following a book,published on 1988. For this reason, this type of main() declaration is in my code. I tried to declare the functions before main() as haccks, but it still shows the same error. and most interesting point here is: main.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `factoor' andmain.c:(.text+0x26b): undefined reference to `eeror' whereas in my code there is no such NAME is present at now(those were present as i made naming mistakes and after FIRST compilation I corrected every naming mistake, but the same mistakes are showing again after following compilation.....)

Comment: That's odd. You're getting link-time errors for functions that are defined in the code you're showing us. I'd expect compile-time warnings or errors, since you call the functions before declaring or defining them, but if the code compiles the linker shouldn't be complaining about those symbols in particular. You should definitely replace your old-style definitions with prototypes and then see what errors you still have.

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least part of the problem is in your `Makefile`.

This:

```
main.o: global.h
    cc -c -O main.c
```

says that `main.o` depends on `global.h`, but not on `main.c`. Which means that even if you correct errors in `main.c`, typing `make` won't recompile it, and it will try to re-link with the existing `main.o` compiled from the *old* version of `main.c`.

Fix your `Makefile` so that each `foo.o` depends on the corresponding `foo.c`.

As for your code, it's using old-style function definitions, which have been obsolescent since the 1989 ANSI C standard. It's also calling functions before they've been declared or defined, which is invalid as of the 1999 ISO C standard (that would result in a compile-time warning or error message, not the link-time errors you're seeing).

The first thing I'd do (after fixing the Makefile) is to update all your definitions to a more modern style, and add prototypes to the top of the source file so that everything is declared before it's called.  For example, change this:

```
main(argc,argv) int argc;char *argv[];{
```

to this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

and this:

```
stmts(){
```

to this:

```
void stmts(void) {
```

If you're using gcc (`cc` is commonly a symlink, to `gcc`), use options that will produce more warnings, such as `[g]cc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra`.

Replacing the old-style definitions might not fix the problems you're seeing, and it might not be completely necessary if you're using a compiler that accepts old-style code, but it will make the code easier to maintain and to track down any problems. For example, with old-style definitions the compiler won't complain if you call a function with the wrong number of arguments; with prototypes, it will.

Answer (score 1):

You should add prototypes of your functions before the definition of main (specially for C99 and latter).